# When switching the scene from the level to main menu, scripts aren't loaded and buttons don't work. How do I fix this?

Tags: switch-statement, scene, godot

I'm building a little 2d game with Godot-engine. The program starts in main menu and from there you can start the first level. 
When returning from the first level back to the main screen using a button I've implemented in the pause menu, the main menu looks very different compared to program start and none of the buttons are working anymore. Had anyone here a similar issue and know what to do to fix this?

The scene switch from and to the main menu are both done with

```
#path_to_scene to main screen is here "res://menu/startpage.tscn"
get_tree().change_scene(path_to_scene)
```

[Imgur, right menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3G83K.png), 
[Imgur, wrong menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aml6H.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
get_tree().get_root().get_node("startpage").queue_free() # Free the scene
get_tree().change_scene("res://menu/startpage.tscn")     # Change to the scene
get_tree().reload_current_scene()                        # Reload the actual scene (startpage)
```